# How to create a file name using MySQL or batch file where part of the file contents need to be in the name?

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

OK, here is what I am trying to.

Using MySQL command line, I am running a script and then saving out the data like this:

```
mysql -h DATABASE -u yyyy -pxxxx < E:/Step_2.sql > E:/OUTPUT_YYYY_QQ.csv
```

Now, either using MySQL or a Windows batch command, I want the YYYY and QQ to be a specific value. It isn't the current date though. In this example, I want the YYYY to be 2017 and the QQ to be Q4.

I have flexibility to either:

1. Create a new table in SQL with the values in it if needed. Then with help run a command to use those values as part of the file name.
2. Or I can place a file on the server somewhere to "reference" in order to grab the data and place it in the file name.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not familiar with windows, if you can run the same in Linux then I can help you.

Comment: How would you suggest I do it in Linux @vivek?  I may be able to convert from Linux to Windows...

Comment: I have posted the answer in Linux, try to convert into windows batch file. Next time I will start working on Windows as well.

Comment: [13.2.10.1 SELECT ... INTO Syntax :: SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) and [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) statements can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created a shell script called "test.sh", which will generate the file name dynamically, but all you need to convert this shell script into windows batch. It's an idea to you as per your comment.

**test.sh**

```
file_name=$(mysql -N -hlocalhost -uvivek -pvivek -e "select concat('OUTPUT_',year(date_column),'_Q',quarter(date_column),'.csv') file_name from table_name")
mysql -hlocalhost -uvivek -pvivek </home/vivekanand/vivek/stack/test.sql >/home/vivekanand/vivek/stack/$file_name
```

After running the script, I got file created as below with correct output of SQL file "test.sql"

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vivekanand vivekanand 14535 May  7 13:56 OUTPUT_2017_Q4.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Vivik.  Challenge is, as I mentioned, the date is not based on the current date.  The Q4 2017 in my example above can be stored in a table in the database or in a file on the file system...any ideas on how to pull that data into the filename?

Comment: See my updated answer, In Linux it's very easy to do that. But I don't know exactly how you will implement in windows.